# Storing a Meta-Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, entity-attribute-value

I'm at somewhat of a disagreement with a fellow colleague on this issue. First and foremost, the environment (guaranteed, will not change):

- SQL Server 2008 R2
- ASP.NET MVC 3
- C#

And now, the scenario: I am working on an application which will give users the ability to collect input from users and store it for later reporting purposes. The methods of collecting input are in various types of controls they can place on the page. Collecting the data is not the issue; storing it is.

**Database Within A Database**

I follow the notion that it should be stored as a collection of key-value pairs (in this example, a table called `ResponseItems`):

```
+----------+----------+----+-----+
|ResponseId|FormItemId|Name|Value|
+----------+----------+----+-----+
```

Where the `ResponseId` and `FormItemId` form the primary key, the `ResponseId` relating to a `Response` table, as such:

```
+----------+------+------+-------------+
|ResponseId|FormId|UserId|SubmittedDate|
+----------+------+------+-------------+
```

And the `FormItemId` relating to a `FormItem` table:

```
+----------+------+----+-----------------+
|FormItemId|FormId|Type|InstantiationData|
+----------+------+----+-----------------+
```

Where `FormId` is the same as the `FormId` in the `Response` table, referencing a `Form` table, which is not as important to illustrate.

**XML Serialization**

I get back in response that serializing the form components and responses as XML makes more sense, such that it requires less bulk in terms of tables, leaving only a Form table:

```
+------+--------+
|FormId|Elements|
+------+--------+
```

and all instantiation data is stored within the XML data for each form element in the `Elements`. The responses are then similarly recorded:

```
+----------+------+-------------+----------------+
|ResponseId|UserId|SubmittedDate|ResponseElements|
+----------+------+-------------+----------------+
```

**The Short Question After The Long Preface**

I think the first idea is cleaner and easier to report on. What do you think?

As a final note, there are more tables to this, for both sides, as the forms are to be versioned for every time a user edits the form.

Comment: Personally, I'm partial to the XML storage :)  SQL Server 2008 handles XML really well and so does C#.  For what you are trying to achieve, I think XML is more suited than a database.  The database is just storing your XML for you....though, I am admittedly biased to this opinion.

Comment: Indeed you are biased to this. As well you know how much more complex this is than just this simplified layout. :)

Comment: Yes, I am very well aware of the complexity of the project...I'm looking forward to seeing some of the suggestions from the SO community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first approach is called Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV).  In my opinion this is *never* a good way to store relational data.  You should read an article called [Bad CaRMa](http://www.simple-talk.com/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/) before you adopt that design.

I also talk about the disadvantages of EAV in my presentation [Practical Object-Oriented Models in SQL](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-object-oriented-models-in-sql) and in my book [SQL Antipatterns Volume 1: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/).

Of these two designs, I would prefer the XML approach.  It's basically Martin Fowler's  [Serialized LOB](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serializedLOB.html) pattern.

You might also want to read [How FriendFeed Uses MySQL to Store Schema-less Data](http://bret.appspot.com/entry/how-friendfeed-uses-mysql).  Their approach is not specific to MySQL; it would work in SQL Server or any other RDBMS.

Comment: What's the short version of why it's a bad idea? The article seems interesting, but not fully relevant, and I'm not really interested in being sold a book as an answer.

Comment: The short version is that data in that form is not a relation, so many features of SQL cease to work as expected.  Data types, constraints, schema, etc. go out the window.  You might as well store as XML in a series of files, not in an RDBMS.

Comment: FWIW, any time I mention my book on SO, I first offer a free source of similar information.  I don't want to be a spammer, but I wrote my book to help people with questions exactly like yours.

Comment: I took a look at your slideshare presentation, and it gets the point across as to why it can be a dangerous thing to go with EAV. How do you ease the reporting concerns on XML data with the alternate approach?

Comment: If you want to do reporting with SQL, then store the data in discrete columns and customize the schema to fit your data.  If you store XML as a Serialized LOB, then reporting is up to you to implement in application code.  Sorry, you can't take away the schema and expect SQL to do the work.

Comment: Excellent book, btw - well worth the $$ it costs and should be a **must read** for any serious database developer!